# Zero value when computing an integral in 4-dimensions using quasi-Monte Carlo quadrature

Tags: python, numerical-integration, scipy.stats, quad, n-quads

Calculate the value of the integral using the _nquad method. The value is 2.9613231498508394e-18 but the solution takes a long time. qmc_quad can be used for acceleration, but the value remains 0.
Where could there be a mistake? Or am I doing something wrong?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime.now()

XX = [None, 11.3, 14.8, 7.6, 10.5, 12.7, 3.9, 11.2, 5.4, 8.5, 5.0, 4.4, 7.3, 2.9, 5.7, 6.2, 7.3, 3.3, 4.2, 5.5, 4.2]
number_i = [None, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
N = 20


def F(M1, Mn, S1, Sn, i, n, x):
    M = (M1 * (n - i) / (n - 1)) + (Mn * (i - 1) / (n - 1))
    S = (S1 * (n - i) / (n - 1)) + (Sn * (i - 1) / (n - 1))
    y = (x - M) / S
    f = np.exp(-0.5 * y * y) / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)
    pdf = f / S
    return pdf


def G(args):
    M1, Mn, S1, Sn = args
    # unpacked values x and i
    x = XX[1:]
    i = number_i[1:]
    # Calculate the value of the function F for each x and i
    values = [F(M1, Mn, S1, Sn, i_val, 20, x_val) for i_val, x_val in zip(i, x)]
    result = np.prod(values)
    return result


# limits of integration for M1,Mn,S1,Sn a=lower, b=upper
a = (-100, -100, 0.0001, 0.0001)
b = (100, 100, 100, 100)

K, _ = integrate.qmc_quad(G, a, b, n_estimates=4, n_points=204800)

print(K)
print(datetime.datetime.now() - start)
# result module nquad
# K = (2.9613231498508394e-18, 9.999964969225108e-21)
# result module qmc_quad
# K = (0, 0)
```

Comment: Can you provide coordinates at which the value of the integrand G is (numerically) nonzero?

Comment: At least part of the problem is that your function `G` returns a scalar. According to the documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.qmc_quad.html), the integrand must "be vectorized to accept an array of shape (d, n_points), where d is the number of variables (i.e. the dimensionality of the function domain) and n_points is the number of quadrature points, and return an array of shape (n_points,), the integrand at each quadrature point.

Comment: @MattHaberland Yes, for M1 limits - 5, 15; for Mn - 0, 7; for S1 - 0, 10; for Sn - 0, 6.

Comment: Got it, but as I mentioned in the second comment, I realized that the first problem to address is that the function isn't vectorized appropriately. I might have time to address that, but can you tell me what this is? I see hints of the normal distribution pdf. If so, there may be other ways to solve your problem that are even more appropriate.

Comment: @MattHaberland Good! Thank you for your question. The task is to find estimates of the parameters of a normal distribution (mean and standard deviation), but in this case, both parameters have dynamic properties. As a result, their behavior depends on the number of tests (as indicated in the initial data for the X-test implementation and the number of test), which are represented by functions M(M1, Mn) and S(S1, Sn).
We substitute all known values into the probability distribution of the normal curve, or rather, from the product of each individual test.

Comment: However, I solved this problem using the maximum likelihood method, which allows us to find the maximum value of the function to obtain estimates for the parameters.
Additionally, there is a new approach that relies on constructing probability distributions for parameter estimates, and to do this, it is necessary to calculate the factor K. Once we have obtained this value, we can divide the function G by K to obtain the desired result.And we obtain the probability density function of the parameter estimates. After that, we will need to integrate further, with 3D integration.

Comment: @MattHaberland 
Matt Haberland, if you would like to learn more about this, I would be happy to explain it. This method is known as the unbiased estimation technique and it is a new approach! It allows us to obtain unbiased and precise parameter estimates with a smaller sample size.
That's what I want to tell you. The maximum likelihood and least squares methods produce biased estimates of parameters. In contrast, the method of unbiased estimation is an order of magnitude more accurate.